# Java | TicTacToe Right Diagonal Not Working

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, diagonal

currently working on a tic tac toe game in java, and I have a checkWin() method that works correctly for 3 out of the 4 possible winning conditions. The one I am having an issue with is the right diagonal.

Code:

```
public boolean checkWin(String player){
    int row = 0; // Holder to count number of player spots in row
    int d1 = 0; // Holder to count number of player spots in right diag.
    int d2 = 0; // Holder to count number of player spots in left diag.
    int[] column = new int[squares[0].length]; /* Holder to count number
    of player spots in column */

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        row = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(null == squares[i][j]){
                continue;
            }
            if(squares[i][j].getText().equals(player)){
                row++; /* If spot at [i][j] equals player, increase row */
                column[j]++; /* If spot at [i][j] equals player, increase 
                col */
                if(i == j){ /* If spot at i is equal to j, increase left 
                    diag */
                    d1++;
                } else if ((size - 1) == i + j){ /* If spot at i + j 
                    equals board size - 1, increase right diag. */
                    d2++;
                }
            }
        }
        if(row == size){ 
            /* 
            if spots in row is equal to size (otherwise, if it fills
            the row, return win
            */
            return true;
        }
    }
    if(size == d1 || size == d2){
        /*
        if spots in either diag is equal to size, return win
        */
        return true;
    } 
    for(int i = 0; i < column.length; i++){
        if(column[i] == size){
            /*
            if column is full of the same player character, return win
            */
            return true;
        }
    }
    /*
    otherwise, return false
    */
    return false;
}
```

The problem part is:

```
                else if ((size - 1) == i + j){ /* If spot at i + j 
                    equals board size - 1, increase right diag. */
                    d2++;
                }
```

Reason for setting it up this way, is how a 2D Array works, so for a 3x3 board:

[00][01][02]

[10][11][12]

[20][21][22]

And with i + j = size - 1, it would evaluate 2 + 0, 1 + 1, 0 + 2 all equal 2, which is size - 1 if size = 3, but when I run the program and perform the right diagonal move, it doesn't return a true value for win.

Any suggestions for how to fix this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _it would evaluate [...] 1 + 1_ No, it won't.  Start your debugger there.

Comment: Okay. I will here in a bit, just left home. But why wouldn't it start there, if you don't mind enlightening me, haha?

Comment: The answer is a few lines above the line you're complaining about.  In the future, I would recommend doing some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) before asking these questions in the future.

Comment: I don't think you can check the diagonals the same way you check the rows and columns.  There are three rows and three columns, six total, but only two diagonals.  I don't think the diagonals belong inside the for loop.

Comment: Markspace, Makes sense, but why does the left diagonal work within the loop while the right doesn't? And if not a loop, how would I access the values of a board with varying sizes?

Comment: Your issue has nothing whatsoever to do with your loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else if ((size - 1) == i + j)
```

^ This is only evaluated if the `if` condition above it is false.

```
if(i == j)
```

When `i == 1` and `j == 1`, then `i == j` is true, and thus `(size - 1) == i + j` is not evaluated.

TLDR: Get rid of your `else`.

Comment: That did the trick, goodness I feel dumb. Got so used to using else if that I figured I needed it. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is exactly why I said to try debugging first before asking this question.